# Using TextIO.Write with a complicated PCollection type in Google Cloud Dataflow

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a PCollection that looks like this:

```
PCollection<KV<KV<String, EventSession>, Long>> windowed_counts
```

My goal is to write this out as a text file.  I thought to use
something like:

```
windowed_counts.apply( TextIO.Write.to( "output" ));
```

but am having a hard time getting the Coders setup correctly.   This is what I thought would work:

```
    KvCoder kvcoder = KvCoder.of(KvCoder.of(StringUtf8Coder.of(), AvroDeterministicCoder.of(EventSession.class) ), TextualLongCoder.of());
    TextIO.Write.Bound io = TextIO.Write.withCoder( kvcoder );
    windowed_counts.apply( io.to( "output" ));
```

where TextualLongCoder is my own subclass of AtomicCoder, analogous to TextualIntegerCoder.  The EventSession class is annotated to use AvroDeterministicCoder as it's default coder.

But with this I get garbled output that includes non-textual character, etc.   Can anybody advice on how you would write this particular PCollection out as text?  I'm sure there's something obvious I'm missing here...

Comment: What kind of output format are you expecting? For example, do you want a comma delimited file?

Comment: That part isn't even all that important to me... if it's space delimited, or comma delimited, whatever.  I'm just struggling to figure out how to get it written out in any textual format right now.

Comment: Also I see you're not using generics so maybe there is a hidden mismatch in arguments that might be causing it?

Answer (score 4):

Did you try creating a transform that will convert a `PCollection` of `KV<KV<String, EventSession>, Long>` to a `PCollection` of `String`s and then writing it into a text file?

I found it to be most flexible way for my needs

Comment: No, but that was my plan if I couldn't find a more straightforward way to do it.

Comment: As GB notes, this is the right solution to this problem.