# How to use a custom Coder in a PCollection<KV<String, B>>?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to use a custom `Coder` so that I can do some transforms, but I'm having trouble getting the `PCollection` to use my custom coder, and I *suspect* (???) it's because it's wrapped in a `KV`. Specifically:

```
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create ...
p.getCoderRegistry().registerCoder(MyClass.class, MyClassCoder.class);

...

PCollection<String> input = ...
PCollection<KV<String, MyClass>> t = input.apply(new ToKVTransform());
```

When I try to run something like this, I get a java.lang.ClassCastException and a stacktrace that includes a `SerializableCoder` instead of `MyClassCoder` like I would expect.

```
[error]     at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.SerializableCoder.decode(SerializableCoder.java:133)
[error]     at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.SerializableCoder.decode(SerializableCoder.java:50)
[error]     at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.KvCoder.decode(KvCoder.java:95)
[error]     at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.KvCoder.decode(KvCoder.java:42)
```

I see that the answer to another, somewhat related question ([Using TextIO.Write with a complicated PCollection type in Google Cloud Dataflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29131859/using-textio-write-with-a-complicated-pcollection-type-in-google-cloud-dataflow)) says to map everything to strings, and use that to pass stuff around PCollections. Is that *really* the recommended way??

(Note: the actual code is in Scala, but I'm pretty sure it's not a Scala <=> Java issue so I've translated it into Java here.)

Update to include Scala code and more background:

So this is the actual exception itself (should have included this at the beginning):

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$SerializationProxy to field com.example.schema.Schema.keyTypes of type scala.collection.immutable.Map in instance of com.example.schema.Schema
```

Where `com.example.schema.Schema` is:

```
case class Schema(id: String, keyTypes: Map[String, Type])
```

And lastly, the `SchemaCoder` is:

```
class SchemaCoder extends com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.coders.CustomCoder[Schema] {
  def decode(inputStream: InputStream, context: Context): Schema = {
    val ois = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream)
    val id: String = ois.readObject().asInstanceOf[String]
    val javaMap: java.util.Map[String, Type] = ois.readObject().asInstanceOf[java.util.Map[String, Type]]
    ois.close()

    Schema(id, javaMap.asScala.toMap)
  }

  def encode(schema: Schema, outputStream: OutputStream, context: Context): Unit = {
    val baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos)
    oos.writeObject(schema.id)
    val javaMap: java.util.Map[String, Type] = schema.keyTypes.asJava
    oos.writeObject(javaMap)
    oos.close()

    val encoded = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(baos.toByteArray()))
    outputStream.write(encoded.getBytes())
  }
}
```

====

Edit2: And here's what `ToKVTransform` actually looks like:

```
class SchemaExtractorTransform extends PTransform[PCollection[String], PCollection[Schema]] {
  class InferSchemaFromStringWithKeyFn extends DoFn[String, KV[String, Schema]] {
    override def processElement(c: DoFn[String, KV[String, Schema]]#ProcessContext): Unit = {
      val line = c.element()
      inferSchemaFromString(line)
    }
  }

  class GetFirstFn extends DoFn[KV[String, java.lang.Iterable[Schema]], Schema] {
    override def processElement(c: DoFn[KV[String, java.lang.Iterable[Schema]], Schema]#ProcessContext): Unit = {
      val idAndSchemas: KV[String, java.lang.Iterable[Schema]] = c.element()
      val it: java.util.Iterator[Schema] = idAndSchemas.getValue().iterator()
      c.output(it.next())
    }
  }

  override def apply(inputLines: PCollection[String]): PCollection[Schema] = {
    val schemasWithKey: PCollection[KV[String, Schema]] = inputLines.apply(
      ParDo.named("InferSchemas").of(new InferSchemaFromStringWithKeyFn())
    )

    val keyed: PCollection[KV[String, java.lang.Iterable[Schema]]] = schemasWithKey.apply(
      GroupByKey.create()
    )

    val schemasOnly: PCollection[Schema] = keyed.apply(
      ParDo.named("GetFirst").of(new GetFirstFn())
    )

    schemasOnly
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you include the Scala code that isn't working?  The snippet that you've posted should work, as long as you are using the same Pipeline object throughout your code.

Comment: @danielm I've updated the original question with more code and background. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Could you also provide the code for ToKVTransform?  Dataflow automatically propagates type information through the transforms in order to infer what Coders to use, and it would be helpful to see exactly what is going on in your case.  Thanks!

Comment: Done! Ignore the poor naming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem doesn't reproduce in Java; Scala is doing something differently with types that breaks Dataflow coder inference.  To work around this, you can call setCoder on a PCollection to set its Coder explicitly, such as

```
schemasWithKey.setCoder(KvCoder.of(StringUtf8Coder.of(), SchemaCoder.of());
```

---

Here's the Java version of your code, just to make sure that it's doing approximately the same thing:

```
public static class SchemaExtractorTransform
  extends PTransform<PCollection<String>, PCollection<Schema>> {
  class InferSchemaFromStringWithKeyFn extends DoFn<String, KV<String, Schema>> {
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
      c.output(KV.of(c.element(), new Schema()));
    }
  }

  class GetFirstFn extends DoFn<KV<String, java.lang.Iterable<Schema>>, Schema> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 0;
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
      c.output(c.element().getValue().iterator().next());
    }
  }

  public PCollection<Schema> apply(PCollection<String> inputLines) {
    PCollection<KV<String, Schema>> schemasWithKey = inputLines.apply(
        ParDo.named("InferSchemas").of(new InferSchemaFromStringWithKeyFn()));

    PCollection<KV<String, java.lang.Iterable<Schema>>> keyed =
        schemasWithKey.apply(GroupByKey.<String, Schema>create());

    PCollection<Schema> schemasOnly =
        keyed.apply(ParDo.named("GetFirst").of(new GetFirstFn()));

    return schemasOnly;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah, there's `KvCoder.of(...)`! Awesome, that should be hint I need; will report back. In the meantime, this gets me further, so the answer works for me. Cheers!